# trying to make a sprite jump

Tags: python, pygame

**When ever i press up arrow the sprite jumps but when it comes down it carrys on going down. Here is my code. it does not do this with left and rght keys.

```
   x = (display_width * 0.1)
y = (display_height * 0.75)
x_change = 0
y_change = 0

over = False
while over == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            over = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -30

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = 30


    x += x_change
    y += y_change
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem with Left & Right?

Comment: Please post code that includes the loop...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `y_change` remaining at `30` during later processing.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        x_change = 0
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x_change = 0
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        y_change = 30                # <=== HERE
```

So when the event fires, the `y_change` becomes 30 - so the position moves back down.  But on the next loop, `y_change` is *still* 30, so it keeps moving down, again and again.

Comment: It should not be if the y_change=0 is inside the event loop. However that is unclear as the posted code was poorly formatted and the loop was not included.

Comment: Ive fixed the code in the post ill go ans have a look at my code to see if this is why